# Upgrade MongoDB Community to Enterprise

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I have a server using MongoDB Community but my client wants additional features that are only able using the Enterprise version.

We're about to buy it, however, I was wondering what should I do to upgrade from Community to Enteprise, and guarantee that all additional features are available.

Is there a license file to add? Should I install from scratch and restore backup? How should I proceed?

Thanks,

Vinicius

Comment: From my personal experience I did new installation. I would check with MongoDB.Inc when you make the purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove community version (packets) and install enterprise version. Simple, nothing else needed. All those enterprise version features have been compiled into.

If you have replica set, you can do this without down time, just do change one (secondary) node at time.

Comment: How do I know what are the packets from the community version? Also, is there any chance to have data loss?

Comment: No data loss. When you install enterprise version, it will tell you if you have forgotten to uninstall some packages.

Comment: I'll give a shot using Community to Enterprise trial and update you here. Cheers

Comment: @JJussi, Can we upgrade directly with-out taking DB backup of community version and install enterprise version so it will manager by mongoDB to migrate Data?

Comment: @Jaymin yes, you can upgrade without backup... Of course, it is always recommended to make the backup. But there should not be any problems.